# How to convert pandas DataFrame to multiple DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My DataFrame

```
df= pandas.DataFrame({
  "City" :["Chennai","Banglore","Mumbai","Delhi","Chennai","Banglore","Mumbai","Delhi"],
  "Name" :["Praveen","Dhansekar","Naveen","Kumar","SelvaRani","Nithya","Suji","Konsy"]
  "Gender":["M","M","M","M","F","F","F","F"]})
```

when printed it appears like this, df=

| City | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chennai | Praveen | M |
| Banglore | Dhansekar | M |
| Mumbai | Naveen | M |
| Delhi | Kumar | M |
| Chennai | SelvaRani | F |
| Banglore | Nithya | F |
| Mumbai | Suji | F |
| Delhi | Konsy | F |

I want to save the data in separate DataFrame as follows:

Chennai=

| City | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chennai | Praveen | M |
| Chennai | SelvaRani | F |

Banglore=

| City | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Banglore | Dhansekar | M |
| Banglore | Nithya | F |

Mumbai=

| City | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mumbai | Naveen | M |
| Mumbai | Suji | F |

Delhi=

| City | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Delhi | Kumar | M |
| Delhi | Konsy | F |

```
My code is:

D_name= sorted(df['City'].unique())
for i in D_name:
   f"{i}"=df[df['City']==I]
```

The dataset have more than 100 Cities.How do I write a for loop in python to get output as multiple data frame?

Answer (score 3):

You can groupby and create a dictionary like so:

```
dict_dfs = dict(iter(df.groupby("City")))
```

Then you can directly access individual cities:

```
Delhi = dict_dfs["Delhi"]
print(Delhi)

# result:

    City   Name Gender
3  Delhi  Kumar      M
7  Delhi  Konsy      F
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
groups = df.groupby(by='City')

Bangalore = groups.get_group('Bangalore')
```